# Forcefully destroy posix message queue?

Tags: posix, message-queue

I have a hard requirement to forcefully destroy a posix message queue with a given name.

I have found out by trial and error that this command wont do

```
 mq_unlink(BROKER_NAME);
```

The problem with above is that even after unlink, the queue exists as long as other threads/processes reference it.

Is there a way to forcefully destroy the queue, no questions asked?

I will also have file descriptor to the queue.

Answer (score 1):

You can not force the queue to be destroyed as long as it's still in use

Per [POSIX `mq_unlink()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mq_unlink.html) (bolding mine):

> If one or more processes have the message queue open when `mq_unlink()` is called, **destruction of the message queue shall be postponed** until all references to the message queue have been closed.

You have to have all processes using the queue also close their connection(s).

Comment: Thanks so does that mean that if N procs are using the queue, they all have to mq_unlink it?

Comment: @Ace  `mq_close()` should be sufficient (POSIX says "closed").  But you should probably test things to be sure - and beware race conditions where a process tries to recreate the queue after you call `mq_unlink()`.

Comment: Which is the big problem I am running into. I am not able to reliably recreate the queue after deletion. I get return value of -1 from mq_open and errno 22, which is hinting at the queue already exists error.

Comment: @Ace are you sure errno 22 indicates what you think it does?  You may have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here.

Comment: @pilcrow I think so, since if you restart the process, the queue creation completes successfully returning a positive fd the first time mq_open() is invoked.